# ST-LINK server preventing debugging. 'Info : stlinkserver already running, exit'

Tags: stm32, nucleo, stm32h7

Just trying to build and run / debug the default, unedited STM32 project you get when you open STM32CubeIDE. After telling me I needed the download the ST-Link server for it to work, I did, then updated the board when prompted. It now gives me 'Info : stlinkserver already running, exit' and the program times out.

If it's already running, how can I turn it off? Or have I configured something incorrectly?

Comment: Try restarting your computer.

Comment: No dice unfortunately. Thank you for helping though